# Wightman distributions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, wightman-fields

According to the Wightman axioms, for Wightman fields $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n$, the vacuum expectation value
$$\langle\Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n)\Omega\rangle$$
is a multilinear continuous map from an n-tuple product of Schwartz spaces to the complex numbers, i.e.:
$$\langle\Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n)\Omega\rangle : \underbrace{\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^4) \times \dots \times \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^4)}_{n \text{ times}} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}. $$

Then the nuclear theorem states that there is a unique tempered distribution $\mathcal{W}: \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{4n}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that:
$$\langle\Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n)\Omega\rangle = \mathcal{W}(f), $$

where $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = f_1(x_1)\cdot f_2(x_2) \cdot \dots \cdot f_n(x_n)$.

This distribution is then suddenly written as $\mathcal{W}(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \langle \Omega, \phi_1(x_1)\dots\phi_n(x_n) \Omega \rangle$.

This does not make sense as $\mathcal{W}$ is not a function of $n$ four-vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbb{R}^4$. What does this notation mean?

Comment: The exact same thing $\delta(x)$ denotes: it is a symbolic notation, whose actual meaning is $\delta(f):=f(0)$.

Comment: But for the Dirac delta, there's a clear intuitive meaning that's lacking here.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that 
 $$\int \mathcal{W}(x_1,\dots,x_n) f(x_1)\cdots f(x_n) dx_1\cdots dx_n= \langle \Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n) \Omega \rangle\:.$$
in distributional sense: there is a Schwartz distribution of ${\cal S}'(\mathbb R^4 \times \cdots \times \mathbb R^4)$ denoted by $\mathcal{W}$ whose action on functions of ${\cal S}(\mathbb R^4 \times \cdots \times \mathbb R^4)$ with  the *special* form $f_1\otimes \cdots \otimes f_n$ gives $\langle \Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n) \Omega \rangle$. Another (perhaps less ambiguous) form for this statement is the following one.

*There exists $\mathcal{W} \in {\cal S}'(\mathbb R^4 \times \cdots \times \mathbb R^4)$ such that
$$\mathcal{W}(f_1\otimes \cdots \otimes f_n)= \langle \Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n) \Omega \rangle\:,$$
for every choice of $f_k \in {\cal S}(\mathbb R^4)$, $k=1,2,\ldots, n$.*

Comment: But what does that integral mean? I would just write $\mathcal{W}(f)$, where $f$ is defined as in the question. Writing $\mathcal{W}(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ implies that $\mathcal{W}$ is dependent on the vectors $x_i$, even if you write in in an integral, so I don't understand what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: ${W}(x_1,\dots,x_n) $ is the formal kernel of a distribution. That is not an integral in proper sense. TSchwart's  nuclear theorem implies that the map $f_1\otimes \cdots \otimes f_n \mapsto \langle \Omega, \phi_1(f_1)\dots\phi_n(f_n) \Omega \rangle$ is the restriction of a distribution whose action is formally indicated by an integration.

Comment: So it's just an informal way of writing things? I think I get it, but I still think it's a weird way of writing things.

Comment: It is nothing but the way used by physicists....

Comment: It's not even that weird.  Schwarz functions are dense in the space of distributions.  Take an approximating sequence, and the natural pairing is approximated by integration.